# Auto resize text within a constrained button on storyboard

Tags: ios, button, text, xcode6, autoresize

I have a universal app which i used the story board to constrain a button so that from the iPhone 4 to the iPhone 6plus, the size will be well proportioned to the device's screen. The title of the button is the number "2" (All that is shown on the screen is the number "2" which can be pressed). For some reason I cannot figure out how to auto resize the font with the button size so that the number looks proportioned to the screen as intended. 
Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

1. Use Interface Builder only. You can add an UILabel as the same size as your button. Remove the title of Your button. Set text for the UILabel. Then change the AutoShrink property of the UILabel to "Minimum Font Scale". But you will not able to change the text color for different states.
2. Use code to fit width. Try this:

   ```
   self.yourButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
   self.yourButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
   ```
3. If you want to fit the height of title. Maybe you must calculate the height by yourself. Use [font lineHeight] to make sure the font fit your button.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function (from e.g. viewDidAppear) for every button in your app:

```
func setAppropriateFontSize( butt:UIButton){
    let maxFontSize = butt.frame.height
    butt.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", maxFontSize)
    butt.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    butt.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
}
```

Above, `maxFontSize` is the maximum font-size for which the text still fits vertically within the button. This font is probably too large, and therefore we allow it to *shrink* (`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` means that we allow the font to *shrink*, as it will never increase to fit the width).